# access a zipped file without unzipping?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, zip, winzip

My program produces a log of info every hour that the system is running, that contains various data like access times, data transfers and any faults/warnings experienced. unfortunately these log files can be anywhere from 10,000KB to 25,000KB in size, so I've begun zipping them individually once they're at least 24hr old, this way my system has only 24 unzipped log files at any one time.

The issue I need to resolve is that part of this software is a 'Diagnostics' window, where the user can load up log files from a selected date range based on file's creation time and view their contents in an easy to read format. I understand that in order for the files to show up in their search there must be an exception allowing .zip to be checked as well, but I cannot access any of the file's data to see if said .zip files fall into the date range.

My question is: is their a way for me to access the zipped file's information (and to further extent it's contents) without having to unzip the files, do the search, re-zip the files? that seems like too much work to unzip one hundred or more files if only 1 or 2 fall in your date range.

Comment: Use the file's creation/modify time...

Comment: it may help to read up on what zipping a file does

Comment: you can see the zip header file (file names and size) but for getting the data from a specific file, you need unzipping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a timestamp to the filename of each zipped file.

In general, when you zip a file you're putting the actual data of the file into a format that is unreadable. Most zipping algorithms (keep in mind that there are very many) work on a very bit-hacky level, which is why you really need to unzip the files to get your original data out. (There's no such thing as a free lunch.)

Luckily though, a file is not just a file! Because you're totally right, having to read a file to do things with it would be terrible! Imagine having to search a file system if you had to read each file to figure out where in the directory it was.

There are a number of ways to access the metadata associated with your file depending on what exact system you're on. For instance, in unix-style machines using the command `ls -l` will get you the last edited information.

That said, log files usually have names that start with a timestamp for this exact reason. If you want to keep your filenames pretty though, going through the last-edited date is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

A good zip library (e.g. [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/)) ought to allow you to iterate over the files contained in the archive without extracting them.  This will allow you to query the associated file dates. For example, using the aforementioned SharpZipLib, you would just need to inspect the DateTime property of the `ZipEntry` objects contained in the archive.

Comment: I would argue that if you're not actually zipping or unzipping any files a library like SharpZibLib is serious overkill.

Comment: not allowed to use non in-house libraries for the most part. licensing issues as this is a for profit software